# Find the min. distance of each pixel to a connected component

Tags: r, masking

I have a matrix in a similar format to the following

```
a = [1, 1, 0, 0;
     1, 1, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0,
     2, 2, 2, 2]
```

This matrix represents a mask over a region, where each connected component represented by a unique value, e.g 1, 2, 3.

I would like to calculate the min. distance of each pixel to a specified connected component. For instance, if I want to calculate the min. distance of each pixel to the connected component 2, then I would get an output as

```
b = [3, 2.23, 2, 2;
     2, 1.4, 1, 1;
     1, 1, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0]
```

where each cell has the unit of pixel to represent distance.

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Should the bottom row of your output matrix be zeroes, because those are the "2" component pixels, and the distance to the nearest "2" component is therefore zero? I also don't understand the two "2"s on the third row since they only seem to be one unit from the nearest "2" (the bottom row)... (Or am I wrong to assume this is a 4x4 matrix? Because this isn't R, it looks like maybe Matlab?)

Comment: @Spacedman yes you are right. that is a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `raster` package to handle gridded data:

```
> a = raster(t(matrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2),4,4)))
```

I've arranged that matrix such that `as.matrix` will print the matrix in your format:

```
> as.matrix(a)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    0
[2,]    1    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    2    2    2    2
```

Then that can be convert to points:

```
> pts = data.frame(rasterToPoints(a))
> head(pts)
      x     y layer
1 0.125 0.875     1
2 0.375 0.875     1
3 0.625 0.875     0
4 0.875 0.875     0
5 0.125 0.625     1
6 0.375 0.625     1
```

These are the cell centre locations, and the whole grid has a bounding box of (0,1),(0,1), but this can be changed with raster package functions.

Anyway, next use the `FNN` package to get the distance from those points to a subset of those points, for example the "1" cluster:

```
> library(FNN)
> b = knnx.dist(data=pts[pts[,3]==1,1:2], query=pts[,1:2], k=1)
> b
           [,1]
 [1,] 0.0000000
 [2,] 0.0000000
 [3,] 0.2500000
 [4,] 0.5000000
```

To make this into a raster, make a copy of the first raster and replace the values:

```
> b = a
> b[] = knnx.dist(data=pts[pts[,3]==1,1:2], query=pts[,1:2], k=1)
> as.matrix(b)
     [,1] [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.00 0.00 0.2500000 0.5000000
[2,] 0.00 0.00 0.2500000 0.5000000
[3,] 0.25 0.25 0.3535534 0.5590170
[4,] 0.50 0.50 0.5590170 0.7071068
```

For the "type 2" cluster the result is different to your output but I think this is right. The nearest "2" is directly below each cell because the "2" cells are all on the bottom:

```
> b[] = knnx.dist(data=pts[pts[,3]==2,1:2], query=pts[,1:2], k=1)
> as.matrix(b)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
[2,] 0.50 0.50 0.50 0.50
[3,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
[4,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

Note the only difference there is the subsetting of `==2` for the "data" argument of `knnx.dist`.